# How to go back to previous page after login?

Tags: commerce-cloud, b2c

How can i modify the logic to redirect the customer to last visited valid page. For example when customer is in PDP and logs in, they should be redirect back to PDP and not the account page

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this:

1. Add a parameter that you pass on during the process
2. Use the [Click Stream](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/DWAPI/scriptapi/html/api/class_dw_web_ClickStream.html) (only available if the customer allows tracking - GDPR)
3. Store it in the session

Comment: i tried using Click Stream. i still get redirected to the account page. do i need to extend the controller? or just the helper file? also, how do i store it in session? i get warnings that i can't store objects in sessions